# Move UIManagedDocument to MagicalRecord

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I have a app that uses UIManagedDocument to initiate core data, i'm interested in using MagicalRecord.

users of the app may have 10 thousands of record in core data, so I want to avoid a manual data migration, so is there a way to initiate MagicalRecord using existing data store created by UIManagedDocument?